# Destroying a user(devise) and perform other tasks as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I use Devise for my users model. I want when a user cancel his account:

```
Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %>
```

to also execute some other tasks like in my case cancel user's Stripe subscription. So i am not sure if what I've done is ok but I created this method into users_controller.rb:

```
  def destroy
    @user = current_user
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripe_customer_token)
    customer.cancel_subscription()
    if @user.destroy
      flash.alert = "Your subscription and account has been cancelled successfully!"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

I think this method is not even executed as when I cancel my account the flash message is different.

Where am I wrong? Is this possible? Because I have the feeling that what I try to do is wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link to the destroy action instead of `registration_path`

```
Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", user_path(user), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: oh snap... sometimes i don't see the obvious solution :) Thanks!